# is there a `transpose-page` command?

Tags: text-editing

Does Emacs or any packages provide a `transpose-page` command?

I know the `C-x [` and `C-x ]` and forward or backward page, but many times I just want to transpose two adjacent pages, especially when in some Major Modes where pages are defined to be some group of special things.

Comment: You could write a command to do that. I don't think there is one that already exists for it. Or you could: (1) select the first page as the region and kill it: `C-SPC C-x ] C-w`, (2) move to the end of the second page and yank the first page there: `C-x ] C-y`. You can put that in a keyboard macro and repeat it any number of times, etc.

Comment: There is a standard `mark-page` command and binding, so you can simplify that macro to `C-x C-p C-w C-x ] C-y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "transpose" functionality is beautifully abstracted such that to implement a new variant you need only give it a single function which knows how to move backward and forward over the thing in question.

Emacs doesn't provide `transpose-pages` by default, but it *does* provide the `forward-page` function we need, and so it is trivial to write the new command.

Here I've copied and pasted `transpose-paragraphs` and substituted "page" appropriately.

```el
(defun transpose-pages (arg)
  "Interchange the current page with the next one.
With prefix argument ARG a non-zero integer, moves the current
page past ARG pages, leaving point after the current page.
If ARG is positive, moves the current page forwards, if
ARG is negative moves it backwards.  If ARG is zero, exchanges
the current page with the one containing the mark."
  (interactive "*p")
  (transpose-subr 'forward-page arg))
```